# Return JSON or template based on query parameter with django restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

'''

```
class ProfileList(APIView): 
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'profile_list.html'

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Profile.objects.all()
        return Response({'profiles': queryset})
```

'''

As documented, the above View renders and returns a html template. However, how to control the view to return the json or html template in the view? For example, by providing parameter as ?type=html, it returns the html page; and with ?type=json it return the json data.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this condition (also add `*args, **kwargs` to the `get` method - good practice for future).

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    if (response_type := request.GET.get("type")) and response_type == "json":
        return JsonResponse({'profiles': queryset})
    return Response({'profiles': queryset})
```

Comment: any solution with only restframework's Response ?

Comment: Just like https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#varying-behaviour-by-media-type but not clear how it works